# How can i make my html5 video to start as range sliders value changes

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

i am building a html5 video with a range slider, i want if i should move the slider, the video should start and stop automatically depending on the value of the range slider, i have done that but it takes long before the video would start, how can i make the video to start as soon as the value of the range slider changes

Here's my code test.page.html

```
<video id="video" playsinline src="{{videoSrc}}#t={{range.min}},{{range.max}}" #video (loadedmetadata)="onMetadata(video)"></video>
<div class="wrap" role="group" aria-labelledby="multi-lbl">
                <label class="sr-only" for="a">Value A:</label>
                <input name="center" id="a" type="range" min="0" [max]="VidDuration" [(ngModel)]="range.center"/>
                <label class="sr-only" for="a">Value A:</label>
                <input (ngModelChange)="onChangeVal(1)" name="min" id="a" type="range" min="0" [max]="VidDuration" [(ngModel)]="range.min"/>
                <label class="sr-only" for="b">Value B:</label>
                <input (ngModelChange)="onChangeVal(2)" name="max" id="b" type="range" min="0" [max]="VidDuration" [(ngModel)]="range.max"/>
            </div>
```

Here's my code test.page.ts

```
onChangeVal(w) {
    let video:any = document.getElementById("video");
    video.pause()
    if(w==1) this.range.max=(this.range.max <= this.VidDuration) ? this.range.min+this.max : this.VidDuration
    else if((this.range.max-this.range.min)>this.max) this.range.min=this.range.max-this.max 
    else if(this.range.max <= this.range.min) this.range.max=this.range.min
    video.currentTime = this.range.min;
    video.play();
}
```

Pls guys, how can i make the video to start as soon as the value of the range slider changes

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event):

> The change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.

Text inputs for example only fire the `change` event when the input loses focus.

You can use [the `input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) instead.

> The `input` event is fired every time the `value` of the element changes. This is unlike the `change` event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

Comment: What i mean is that even when i stop sliding the range slider, it takes like 15-20 seconds before the video will play again

Comment: What web server is hosting the video? Does it support range requests? If not then the browser has to download everything from the beginning of the video to the specified time which might account for the delay.